# Using Http get Service in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have included angular service in my project but the problem is it neither gives an error

nor called i don't know where is problem where as the second object is called

here is code for controller

```
var CreateController = ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.mydata = 'ajs works';
    $http.get('/Testing/Index').success(function(data){
        $scope.model = data;

    });
}];
```

and here is my view where i manipulate the angular js

```
<div ng-controller="CreateController">
    <table class="ui-sortable-handle">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="{{model.Questions.AddQuestionID}}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="complevel" value="{{model.Questions.ComplexityLevel}}" />
                <input type="hidden" id="servcomplvl" value="{{model.servercomplevel}}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Question: {{model.Questions.Question}}</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in model.Options">
            <td class="switch radius">
                <input id="{{item.Options}}" type="radio" name="selectedvalue" value="{{item.Options}}">
                <label for="{{item.Options}}"></label>{{item.Options}}
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    {{mydata}}
```

{{mydata}} this object works where as model object does not work please suggest what to do

Comment: If you open the browser's develper tools, do you see any script errors or errors in network resources?

Comment: no i did not see any error there

Answer (score 2):

It probably does give an error, but you didn't include a callback for it.

```
$http.get('/Testing/Index')
.success(function(data){
    $scope.model = data;
})
.error(function(data){
    console.log("error");
});
```

Comment: where i return from server is this return View(vm);

Comment: If you setup a working example of the problem in http://plnkr.co/ it'll be easier to spot the problem for us.

Comment: i did there but there i don't have my server controller so in $http.get() what URl i have to pass

Comment: Maybe you should use JSFiddle instead. There you can use /echo/json and echo/html to simulate remote resources.